# Container queries: Why can't I style the container selector in the container query

Tags: css, container-queries

When using container queries. I can't style the element that the container query is set on in the container query itself. Like below.

```css
.container {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: hotpink;
  container-type: inline-size;
}

@container (max-width: 768px) {
  /* This selector doesn't work here */
  .container {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Does anyone know why this can't be done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the main issue is:

- the `@container` targets things inside the container element so you cannot target the container itself

Below is the container with a test div that swaps background colour using the container query.

If you put the width back onto the container, then it will only show one background and therefore the need for the query is lost as the container can't change size.

```css
.container {
  container-type: inline-size;
}

.test {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: hotpink;
}

@container (max-width: 768px) {
  .test {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="test"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a pity, it requires us an extra parent container then. I wanted to be able to change the flex properties of the container based on the container width.

Comment: I wanted to be able to remove a child completely (display none) from a flex container when the child width was 0. Doesn't seem like it's possible with container queries or even style queries

Comment: i mean shadowDOM has :host, \@scope has :scope, \@container needs :container.
would be especially useful with \@container style()